# Ant: find: missing argument to `-exec'

Tags: linux, ant, find, exec, sudo

I am trying to add this command to our ant build script:

```
sudo find app/cache/ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

I have tried many variations in the build.xml and I get the same error every time:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Here is what I have tried:

**a**

```
<exec executable="sudo" failonerror="true" osfamily="unix">
    <arg value="find"/>
    <arg value="app/cache/"/>
    <arg value="-type"/>
    <arg value="d"/>
    <arg value="-exec"/>
    <arg value="chmod"/>
    <arg value="775"/>
    <arg value="{}"/>
    <arg value="\;"/>
</exec>
```

**b**

```
<exec executable="sudo" failonerror="true" osfamily="unix">
    <arg line="find app/cache/ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;"/>
</exec>
```

I have also tried escaping `{}` as `\{}` in both versions.

Update: I also even tried this, not sure what I am doing anymore :)

```
<exec executable="sudo" failonerror="false" osfamily="unix">
    <arg line="find app/cache/ -type d"/>
    <arg line="-exec chmod 775 \{} \;"/>
</exec>
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently escaping it was the problem, I had to remove all the \, even the one before \;

```
<exec executable="sudo" failonerror="true" osfamily="unix">
    <arg line="find app/cache/ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} ;"/>
</exec>
```

Comment: Yes it was. The last argument of your command is/was not `\;` but `;`. The backslash is for the shell (otherwise the shell would interpret `;` as the end of the command) whereas `ant` _sees_ the two characters and gives them as an argument (which is not what `find` expects). Note: `sudo find app/cache/ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;` **is** `sudo find app/cache/ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} ";"`. Your first try (a) should work too without the back-slash.

Answer (score 2):

ANT has a [chown task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/chown.html) which can operate on a fileset or dirset.

```
  <target name="changeperms">
    <chmod perm="775" verbose="true">
      <dirset dir="app"/>
    </chmod>
  </target>
```

Just run the ant build under sudo, if you need more privilege:

```
sudo ant changeperms
```